Popen does not raise exception
Popen is not raising an exception and so am unable to catch it. Am I missing anything? It prints the error on terminal window as if it succeded. Refer picture. However it lauches properly if valid argument is given.
import subprocess
try:
    subprocess.Popen(["xdg-open", "invalid"])
    print("Launched")
except:
    print("Exception")


Environment: Python 3.10.12 [GCC 11.4.0], Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Found the answer I was looking for:
Popen exception example
Need to do something like this:
import subprocess

try:
    res = subprocess.Popen(["xdg-open", "/home/sandeep/Scripts/ControlPanel/Data/ControlPanel.ini"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)  
    output,error = res.communicate()
    if output:
        print(" ret> ",res.returncode)
        print(" OK> output ",output)
    if error:
        print(" ret> ",res.returncode)
        print(" Error> error ",error.strip())
except:
    print("Exception")

